# how to rewrite a url with two variables using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want rewrite it with a .htaccess i have this url:

```
../index.php?page=details&id=123456
```

like this:

```
../detail/123456
```

but I do not really know how to do this. Could you help me to rewrite this url?
or give me a simple example that I can understand how it works

Comment: is .. the base url or a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=details&id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The first (.*) selects any string, e.g. "details". ([0-9]+) catches a number, in your case "123456"

Finally

```
&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

ensures, that additional parameters are added to your backendscript, too.

Comment: You can substitute the `([0-9]+)` for `(.*)` again if you want two alphanumeric strings, instead of just numbers.

Comment: Isn't this going the opposite direction that the OP wants? It looks to me like you're going from a "neat" style to the query string style, and I think he wanted the reverse.

Comment: @tobis shouldn't we be using `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` or is it not not neccessary?

Comment: if you are using a .htaccess file, it isn't necessary I think. In my case it works without it ;o)

Comment: @Saurabh you only need that if you don't know if the mod_rewrite module is present. It will give a server error if the module is not present which may be preferable (e.g. remind you to include the module in apache).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I use for my webpage when it's in a subdirectory.

```
# "learn/degree/index.php?d=mathematics" shows as "learn/degree/mathematics"
RewriteRule ^learn/degree/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ learn/degree/index.php?d=$1
```

To complete it, remember to write at the beginning of the page this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
```

Here's the 'full' .htaccess I use in my page to give you some idea.

```
#Redirect any www. to the page without it. Helps to keep user logged.
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newfutureuniversity.org [NC]
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newfutureuniversity.org/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Finally working. Rewrite the user so "/student/Username" will internally be "/student/?user=Username"
RewriteRule ^student/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ student/index.php?user=$1

# Rewrite the disciplines so "learn/degree/1" will internally be "learn/degree/index.php?dis=1"
RewriteRule ^learn/degree/([1-4])$ learn/degree/index.php?dis=$1

# Rewrite the degrees so "learn/degree/mathematics" will internally be "learn/degree/index.php?d=mathematics"
RewriteRule ^learn/degree/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ learn/degree/index.php?d=$1

# Rewrite the degrees so "learn/subject/2/5/7" will internally be "learn/subject/index.php?class=2&div=5&section=7"
RewriteRule ^learn/subject/([0-9])$ learn/subject/index.php?class=$1
RewriteRule ^learn/subject/([0-9])/([0-9])$ learn/subject/index.php?class=$1&div=$2
RewriteRule ^learn/subject/([0-9])/([0-9])/([0-9])$ learn/subject/index.php?class=$1&div=$2&section=$3
```

You have to make the links to `../detail/123456`, then the script interpretes it internally as `../index.php?page=details&id=123456`. If you don't want this, then you are looking for a redirect.

Comment: This is only for one variable. OP is asking about 2 variables specifically.

Comment: @ThomasClayson, okay, I put my code so he can see it more clearly. From the OP, I wanted to give him some idea of how it worked so he can work it out by himself.

Comment: Cool, thats good. I've tried to remove my downvote, but it hasn't shown it as edited, which is strange and as such I can't remove it. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, I mind about my answer being a bit useful, not so much about votes nor points (;

Comment: Psh... lies! I have upvoted another one of your good answers to compensate you. ;-) Hope that'll do! Votes are important, as it helps to direct people to the best answers, and your answer is now very useful, and as such it is a shame to direct people who come here away from it.

Comment: Said not so much, not nothing. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    # RewriteBase / add this if necessery, commented intentionally
    RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=details&id=$2

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This would work, but you'll have to add a new rule for each `page`... which is inefficient.

Comment: sure but look that he wants to point /detail page to page=details parameter first parameter not equals to page name as i think right?

Comment: Well first of all he states in the question title that he's looking for a way to route **2 variables** which makes me think that the "detail" bit is also a variable.

Comment: on the another hand it is not so hard to modify string in his php code so more generic rule will give some flexibility in future. Also we can create catch all rule and split string by slash or other arbitrary string like is used in php frameworks for routing classes