# How to change query url pattern when query post like WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I create my own simple post management and I want to change URL path when query in database like WordPress.

example

from this : http://example.com/bob-section/post.php?postlink=how-to-sing-like-barber-with-bieber

to this : http://example.com/bob-section/how-to-sing-like-barber

this is my current .htaccess

```
#Redirect to non www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ...and that isn't working? What result are you seeing?

Comment: this is my current .htaccess for my website

Comment: this is my current .htaccess that do something else. I show it in my question because someone who can answer  concider it becuase it's must working with the current .htaccess. or even suggestion better solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into implementing a router? This will allow you to use your request URI as variables that are split by the '/' symbol.

I personally prefer the [Aura Router](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-routing-in-php-with-aura-router/) because the Aura framework allows you to cherry-pick only the pieces you need, rather than requiring you to download and use an entire framework for only a handful of features.

To start using Aura, you can either download the git repository for the package, and include the 'bootstrap.php', or you can include it via composer.

Here is a fast and really dirty implementation.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
   //This is the file that sets timezones and loads the Aura Router
   require(__DIR__ .'/vendor/aura/router/bootstrap.php');

    //Create the router
    use Aura\Router\RouterContainer;
    $routerContainer = new RouterContainer();

    //This object will let us define routes
    $map = $routerContainer->getMap();

    /*
     * This could be any of the following requests:
     *
     * $map->get()
     * $map->post()
     * $map->patch()
     * $map->delete()
     * $map->options()
     * $map->head()
     */
    $map->get('post', '/blog/{id}', function ($request, $response) {
        $id = (int) $request->getAttribute('id');
        $response->body()->write("You asked for blog entry {$id}.");
        return $response;
    });
```

Here is a small handful of examples of the router's features:

```
//Regex validate a url parameter
$map->get('post', '/blog/{id}', function($request, $response) {...})->tokens(['id' => '\d+'])

//Define the same values as in your URL, and you can use the array values to hold your url parameters. This is useful if you have optional parameters, and want to set your default values for routing in your router, rather than in your models
->values(['id' => null])

//Require request on HTTPS port 443
->secure() 

//Set authorization level for a route (very flexible - you could even use bitmasking if you felt up for it)
->auth(['isAdmin' => true])
```

I have my routing broken into sub-classes, and I abstract parameters out of the map into separate arrays, and then I pass the data to the Aura View library in order to have a very pure MVC structure.

[Here](http://auraphp.com/packages/3.x/Router/) is the full documentation for the router.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but why it got to do anything with router.  Is there any other simple solution. I just want to use for my website.

Comment: Rather than your web server interpreting your URL as a 'folder/folder/file.ext', a router parses your URL into variables. It then organizes paths.

For instance, '/blog' will lead to the main blog page, because you have a case for that. The url '/blog/{id}' will load a frame that runs a database select using that {id} in its where clause.

A practical example is YouTube. You have watched every video in the same HTML view template. The URL just changes what is pulled from the database into the frame.

Comment: Well, hey - if you're just looking to tie this up quick and dirty, you could use the $_GET url variable, but use .htaccess to clean up the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057121/how-to-rewrite-a-url-with-two-variables-using-htaccess

Is this closer to what you are looking for?